# Scaling everything up and down for different devices in UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

Is it possible to have the storyboard scale everything up or down depending on the screen size or do I have to do it programmatically? For example the UI on iPhone 6 plus would look exactly like the one on iPhone 5 but just larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using Aspect Ratio property of AutoLayout.

You can follow this tutorial. It gives a very nice explanation on how to scale everything up by using fix aspect ratio.

http://simblestudios.com/blog/development/percentage-width-in-autolayout.html

Comment: it kind of work but scaling the text is rather difficult

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible. You have to use adaptive layout and size classes.

There's a very nice tutorial for this on the following link.

[beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial)